# When someone calls me, I want to see which number they rang me on

Tags: 7.1-nougat

I have several work phone numbers and redirect them to my personal mobile (I prefer this to having 2 mobiles or dual SIM).  I'm wondering if there is an app or setting which enables me to see which number they dialed to reach me (i.e. my personal or work number?)

I'm on Android 7.1.2 wileyfox swift and prefer to keep unrooted.

Comment: This probably has more to do with the service that you are using to redirect the number.